# Swizzling UIImage.init(named:) returns nil when getting the instance method

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, method-swizzling

I am trying to swizzle `UIImage` init functions but when trying to get the instance function they return nil. Any idea?

```
let instance = class_getInstanceMethod(self, #selector(UIImage.init(named))
let instanceWithBundle = class_getInstanceMethod(self, #selector(UIImage.init(named:in:with)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It returns nil because in Objective-C they are actually class methods:

[`+[UIImage imageNamed:]`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiimage/1624146-imagenamed?language=objc)

[`+[UIImage imageNamed:inBundle:withConfiguration:]`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiimage/3294226-imagenamed?language=objc)

Use `class_getClassMethod` instead (and make sure to add colons after `named` and `with` in your method selectors):

```
let imageNamedMethod = class_getClassMethod(UIImage.self, #selector(UIImage.init(named:)))
let imageNamedInWithMethod = class_getClassMethod(UIImage.self, #selector(UIImage.init(named:in:with:)))
```

Comment: the swizzled init is not being called, any idea?

Comment: @TalZion You should probably make a new question for that, as my answer for that is quite involved (more than I can put in a comment).

Comment: Thanks, here you go @TylerTheCompiler  https://stackoverflow.com/q/60034039/4697535